# Listing Functions In PHP

Tags: php, function

How can i list the all functions i used in my site using php?I used a lot of php functions in my site.If there is any php function to check which functions are used in my site?

Comment: I'm really curious: Why? Are you trying to accomplish something specific or is this just for fun?

Comment: We got it, you want to list them. The question is: what for?

Comment: Only your functions or also all the native PHP functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into running a [phpxref](http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/) on your codebase.

[Example of function documentation output](http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/phpxref-xaraya/_functions/index.html.gz)

Answer (score 1):

Check out doxygen. By running those scripts you will be able to list all functions and classes, and it links them so you can see the usage:

http://www.doxygen.nl/